# Output reverse count foreach loop php

Tags: php, foreach, count, reverse

I have the follow foreach loop:

```
<?php $arrayforward = get_field('background_slider');
        $arrayreversed = array_reverse($arrayforward);
        $count=1;

        foreach($arrayreversed as $subarray) {

        $subfield1 = $subarray['background_image'];
        $subfield2 = $subarray['background_image_alt'];
        $subfield3 = $subarray['text_image'];
        $subfield4 = $subarray['text_image_alt']; ?>

        <div id="slide<?php echo $count; ?>" class="contentslider_wrapper">
            <div class="fullpageimage">
                <img id="slideImg<?php echo $count; ?>" src="<?php echo $subfield1; ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('background_image_alt'); ?>" />
                <img id="textImg<?php echo $count; ?>" class="slidetext" src="<?php echo $subfield2; ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('text_image_alt'); ?>" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php $count++; }; ?>
```

I need help getting the count to reverse. The output I am looking for is as follows:

```
<div id="slide4"></div>
<div id="slide3"></div>
<div id="slide2"></div>
<div id="slide1"></div>
```

Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get the amount of keys in the array and assign it as `$count`, like this:

```
$count = count($arrayreversed);
```

Then replace the `$count++` with `$count--` and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$count=1;` to `$count = sizeof($arrayreversed);`

and `$count++;` to `$count--;`

Answer (score 0):

How about using the size of the array as your initial count and then subtracting 1 each iteration?

```
<?php $arrayforward = get_field('background_slider');
    $arrayreversed = array_reverse($arrayforward);
    $count=count($arrayreversed);

    foreach($arrayreversed as $subarray) {

    $subfield1 = $subarray['background_image'];
    $subfield2 = $subarray['background_image_alt'];
    $subfield3 = $subarray['text_image'];
    $subfield4 = $subarray['text_image_alt']; ?>

    <div id="slide<?php echo $count; ?>" class="contentslider_wrapper">
        <div class="fullpageimage">
            <img id="slideImg<?php echo $count; ?>" src="<?php echo $subfield1; ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('background_image_alt'); ?>" />
            <img id="textImg<?php echo $count; ?>" class="slidetext" src="<?php echo $subfield2; ?>" alt="<?php the_sub_field('text_image_alt'); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $count--; }; ?>
```